# Command line for ESP32 burning

Tags: esp32

I tried to burn it from my GUI (C#) by invoking it from ShellExecute

> Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esptool_py\3.0.0/esptool.exe" --chip esp32 elf2image --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size 4MB -o "main.ino.bin" "main.ino.elf"

Actually it burns but something goes wrong and program doesn't run.

So I go to a build folder - load ***main.ino.partitions.bin*** at address 0x8000 and
***main.ino.bin*** at address 0x10000 with ***flash_download_tool_3.9.2.exe***.
It's burned successfully however program doesn't run. What part do I miss? Why Arduino IDE knows to burn it right and I fail?

Comment: you can see the command in Arduino IDE if you turn on verbose mode in Preferences

Comment: I see it. I show it in my question. But when I execute the line it's burned but program doesn't run. When I burn it from the GUI it runs.

Comment: This command does not write anything to Flash. It converts an ELF executable format into raw binary. You would then have to execute another command to write it.

Comment: Thank you guys. I found the right line in verbose mode.